# How do I add position: absolute to this button in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to add position:absolute to this line of code but i am not sure if thats possible in react js.

```
 <Button href={LINKS.application} external>
          Join today!
        </Button>
```

If it is possible to add position:absolute within that line, please let me know how.

and here is the code in my button component:

```
 export type ButtonProps = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> & {
  iconName?: SupportedIcons
  external?: boolean
  href?: string
  target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ children, external, iconName, disabled, href, target, ...props }) => {
  if (href)
    return (
      <Link href={href}>
        <a
          href={href}
          target={target ?? (external ? '_blank' : '_self')}
          className={`font-secondary text-xs md:text-base flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300 ${
            disabled ? 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-70' : 'cursor-pointer'
          }`}
        >
          {!!iconName && <Icon iconName={iconName} />}
          <span>{children}</span>
          {external && <Icon iconName="arrow" />}
        </a>
      </Link>
    )

  return (
    <button
      {...props}
      disabled={disabled}
      className={`font-secondary text-xs md:text-base flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300 ${
        disabled && 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-70'
      }`}
    >
      {!!iconName && <Icon iconName={iconName} />}
      {children}
      {external && <Icon iconName="arrow" />}
    </button>
  )
}
```

I hope this helps to see where I can add the positioning. Thanks

Comment: That depends on what that `Button` component is and what properties it expects.  We don't know that.

Comment: Hey @David I added the component code. That should make it easier to answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button style={{position:"absolute"}} href={LINKS.application} external>Join today!
</Button>
```

It can be made this way, as inline style

Comment: are you sure, `Button` is a component not the `button` element ...\

Comment: yes, it will work for if that button is a component, also that depends on the package used, if it would accept inline styling

Comment: yeah, that is not clear from the OP

Comment: Hey I added the component code to the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As many comments have said, Button, is a component that I dont know where you got it from, so maybe it is opinionated and wont accept inline styling, but here is how you would do it if Button acts as css buttons.

```
       <Button
          href={LINKS.application}
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '400px', right: '400px' }}
          external
        >
          Join today!
        </Button>
```

Then just change the values for top and right, or write bottom or left if you want. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks! I edited the post with the component code. Please tell me if there is something to do differently now

Comment: Hello @Corey, I am not a typescript master so some of the syntax looks weird to me, but from what i see you made a custom button that relies on the html button tag so just try to do it inline like the answer i gave, or ofc in a css file. If that doesnt work im sorry because i am not skilled enough to help you further. Good luck again :)